# 500 XSRF token mismatch (null). Session may be expired

Tags: post, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to call the rest API for creating a cart with /api/v1/cart on POST method. I tried with and without customer id. But still facing the error. Is there to be configured?? Any help would be great.
Below isthe stackrace of jetty server

### HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /api/v1/cart. Reason:

```
    XSRF token mismatch (null). Session may be expired.
```

#### Caused by:

org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException: XSRF token mismatch (null). Session may be expired.
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.service.ExploitProtectionServiceImpl.compareToken(ExploitProtectionServiceImpl.java:122)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.EstablishSessionFilter.doFilter(EstablishSessionFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at com.anvayin.webapp.CustomCORSFilter.doFilter(CustomCORSFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

--

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that in your site's `web.xml`, `applicationContext-rest-api.xml` is included in the list of `patchConfigLocations` **above** `applicationContext-security.xml`. That `applicationContext-rest-api.xml` excludes the `blCsrfFilte`r for all paths that start with `/api/`:

```
<!-- Set up Spring security for the RESTful API -->
<sec:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="stateless">
    <sec:http-basic />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blRestPreSecurityFilterChain" before="CHANNEL_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blRestCustomerStateFilter" after="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blRestPostSecurityFilterChain" after="SWITCH_USER_FILTER"/>
</sec:http>
```

If you do not have that piece, then Spring Security will throw in the blCsrfFilter into the security filter chain which is required for the site but should be excluded in the Rest APIs. From applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" authentication-manager-ref="blAuthenticationManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <!-- We handle session fixation protection ourselves  -->
    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

   <!-- .................................. -->
   <!-- Other configuration excluded -->
   <!-- .................................. -->

    <!-- Specify our custom filters -->
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blPreSecurityFilterChain" before="CHANNEL_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blCsrfFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blSessionFixationProtectionFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="blPostSecurityFilterChain" after="SWITCH_USER_FILTER"/>
</sec:http>
```